# Is there a consistent way to scrape the first answer from a quora webpage using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I want to scrape the first answer from a given quora webpage. I have written a selenium code to do the same. But it is giving inconsistent results, sometimes it scrapes the first answer from the page but at other times it scrapes 2nd or 3rd answer. Not sure why this is happening, is there a way to fix it?

```
driver.get(('https://www.quora.com/What-is-football'))
questions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ui_qtext_expanded")

l = len(questions)

if l == 0:
    btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui_button_label")
    btn.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    questions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ui_qtext_expanded")

for q in questions:
    print(q.text)
```

This is the code I'm using. I found out that the answers have the class "ui_qtext_expanded" when there is no read more option in the answer. Otherwise it has the class of "ui_qtext_truncated_text" which transitions to "ui_qtext_expanded" when we click on on read more. So I'm always finding the element by classname "ui_qtext_expanded", and if the answer has read more option, length of the questions variable will be 0 and hence we will execute the if block.

This code gives me the first answers from the quora page, but sometimes it gives the second or third answer on the page. How to get the first answer on the page consistently?

Comment: On pages with complex javascript, you might want to add a slight delay between loading and parsing them

Comment: Like at the top, just after loading the webpage but before performing any operation?

Comment: Yes, behind the screen selenium will try to wait ajax operations to complete, but that doesn't always work with complex sequences.